# Optimize search on two related but separate string fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm running ES queries on an object that has

```
{ id, firstName, lastName }
```

and I'd like to allow searching for `John Doe`, but right now if I query that then I get all the objects related to `John` with no preference to `Doe`

I have names mapped as `text` fields, with a analyzer as follows (for our scala elastic client)

```
EdgeNGramTokenizer(
  name = "nGram",
  minGram = 3,
  maxGram = 20
),
LowercaseTokenFilter
```

Then I pass `query(searchString)` into a `must()` search (using elastic4s).

```
searchWithType(kind / kind) from offset size limit query {
    boolQuery().must(query(searchString)).not(filteredNotQueries)
  } sortBy(sorts)
```

Are my mappings incorrect? For the sake of Elastic4s should I combine firstName and lastName?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean query, where you use `must` (which is elasticsearch's way of saying AND).

```
client.execute {
  boolQuery().must(matchQuery("john"), matchQuery("joe"))
}
```